# Copying mosaic dataset from windows ArcMap to linux ArcGIS Server 10.3.1?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, linux, map-service, mosaic-dataset

I have created a mosaic dataset from 12 different images.  This works great inside of ArcMap.  But I have been unable to get it published on my ArcGIS Server.

In my environment, I use the file geodatabase that is duplicated (not a file share).  So I have a local folder containing my file geodatabase (C:\some\dir\file.gdb) and another for my rasters (C:\some\dir\rasters).  Then I create the mosaic in my file geodatabase and add all the rasters from the rasters folder.  Then, when I copy my local folder (C:\some\dir) to the linux server (/opt/some/dir) and register my folder as a data store using the manager web app specifying the different paths for Publisher and Server so that they get translated on a service deploy.

Next I create a simple layer that contains the mosaic, which I *Share As -> Service* to a service definition file.  When I attempt to publish my service the web UI shows a message of `Failed.`, and when I look in the log, i see this message:

```
Instance of the service 'System/PublishingTools.GPServer' crashed. Please see if an error report was generated in '/opt/arcgis/server/usr/logs/xxxxxxx/errorreports'. To send an error report to Esri, compose an e-mail to ArcGISErrorReport@esri.com and attach the error report file.
```

Using this same procedure for normal rasters works just fine, its only the mosaic that is failing.  Initially I thought this could be due to the mosaic having incorrect paths (because i copied it directly to the server not using any publish that would have corrected the different paths).  So I attempted to change the paths using [Modify -> Repair...](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/repairing-paths-in-a-mosaic-dataset.htm).  I then verified the new paths using *Export -> Paths...* and they show the path for the server.  Then I pushed the folder (using rsync) to the server to ensure the new paths have been propagated.  Then I attempted to publish again and the same problem occurred...

Any ideas here?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to add the Image Server extension to use mosaics in Server.

Comment: I do have Image Server...  Still no dice.